# Can't Select Resource Type For Custom Metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I am trying to setup a custom log based metric in Stackdriver and when I try to view it in the Metrics Explorer it doesn't allow me to select a resource type. And if I select the resource type first it doesn't allow me to select the custom metric.

I've tried creating the metric in the project where the resource is located and the project where the Stackdriver Workspace is located but nothing seems to help. I have verified that the filter works and tried just the basic filtering when just looking for my specific search term and also advanced filtering with fields in the log message.

Here is the Custom Metric

[image: Custom Metric]

This is what I see in the Metrics Explorer

[image: Metrics Explorer]

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to solve this one?